# Embedding Lua 5.2 and defining libraries

Tags: c, lua, embed

[Lua](http://www.lua.org) comes with a free on-line [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/) for version 5.2 (which I am using) and [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/#1ed) for version 5.0 is also available.

There have been, however, a couple of changes between these versions that I cannot seem to be able to surpass. The changes are noted in the successive versions of the reference manual for [5.2](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#8) and [5.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#7). Notice the successive deprecation of `luaL_openlib()` in favour of `luaL_register()`, then `luaL_register()` in favor of `luaL_setfuncs()`.

The searches on the web give mixed results, with most of them pointing to `luaL_register()`.

What I try to achieve may be summarized by the mini-program below that may be compiled and linked with say, `gcc ./main.c -llua -ldl -lm  -o lua_test`

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


static int test_fun_1( lua_State * L )
{
    printf( "t1 function fired\n" );
    return 0;
}

int main ( void )
{
    char buff[256];
    lua_State * L;
    int error;

    printf( "Test starts.\n\n" );

    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs( L ); 

    lua_register( L, "t1", test_fun_1 );

    while ( fgets( buff, sizeof(buff), stdin ) != NULL)
    {
      if ( strcmp( buff, "q\n" ) == 0 )
      {
          break;
      }
      error = luaL_loadbuffer( L, buff, strlen(buff), "line" ) ||
              lua_pcall( L, 0, 0, 0 );
      if (error)
      {
        printf( "Test error: %s\n", lua_tostring( L, -1 ) );
        lua_pop( L, 1 );
      }
    }
    lua_close( L );

    printf( "\n\nTest ended.\n" );
    return 0;
 }
```

This works as expected and typing `t1()` produces the expected result.

I would now like to create a library/package visible to Lua. The [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/#1ed) 
advices us [to use](http://www.lua.org/pil/26.2.html) an array and a load function:

```
static int test_fun_2( lua_State * L )
{
    printf( "t2 function fired\n" );
    return 0;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg tlib_funcs [] =
{
  { "t2", test_fun_2 },
  { NULL, NULL }  /* sentinel */
};

int luaopen_tlib ( lua_State * L )
{
  luaL_openlib(L, "tlib", tlib_funcs, 0);

  return 1;
}
```

then use `luaopen_tlib()` after `luaL_openlibs()`. Doing so allows us to use `tlib:t2()` if we define `LUA_COMPAT_MODULE` (work in compatible mode).

What is the proper way of doing this in Lua 5.2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `luaopen_tlib` function should be written that way:

```
int luaopen_tlib ( lua_State * L )
{
  luaL_newlib(L, tlib_funcs);
  return 1;
}
```

And in the `main` function, you should load the module like this:

```
int main ( void )
{
    // ...
    luaL_requiref(L, "tlib", luaopen_tlib, 1);
    // ...
}
```

Or alternatively, you can add an entry `{"tlib", luaopen_tlib}` to the `loadedlibs` table in `linit.c`.

Comment: The luaL_openlibs is optional and probably shouldn't be there (for the example).